# Displaying and converting a date time list field in sharepoint

Tags: c#, list, datetime, sharepoint-2010

I have the following variables to store the value of the list items item for displaying. However one of the fields in the list if a date time field and therefor I am getting an error. I have attempted to convert it a string but have not quite managed to get it to dispay properly.

```
foreach (SPListItem oListItem in listItemCollection)

awardYear = oListItem["Year"].ToString();
awardCategory = oListItem["Category"].ToString();
awardOrganiser = oListItem["Organiser"].ToString();
awardNomWon = oListItem["Nominated/Won"].ToString();

//converting the date time field to a string
DateTime convertedaValue = DateTime.Parse(awardYear);

string awardYearConverted = convertedaValue.ToString();

PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(awardYearConverted + " " + "|" + " " + 
awardCategory + " " + "|" + " " + awardOrganiser + "<br/><br/>"));

//PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(awardOrganiser));


}
```

The problems is that the date time field value is not getting converted. Am I goin about this the right way or not?

Any suggetstion will be greatly appreciated!. Many thanks

Comment: can you show us the value of `awardYear`? I suspect it may be nothing like any string representation of `DateTime`

Comment: There's a lot of processing going on there. First you are converting a Date object to a string, then parsing the string to convert it back to a Date object, then converting to a string again and copying to another string. Just use the first conversion in the literal control - ie LiteralControl(oListItem["Year"].ToString()....

Comment: Hi "StarWho" the value of awardyear is 01/09/2010.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SPUtility.FormatDate(web, DateTime.Parse(oListItem["Year"].ToString()), SPDateFormat.DateTime).ToString();
```